# How to unit test AngularJS $promise.then

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, coffeescript, promise

I have a factory which uses Angular resource to make API call. I then created a function called getAllResources and used the factory to query all of my data. In my controller I then used the service with $promise.then to fetch my data and store it in a variable.

This is in coffeescript. How to unit test this:

Factory:

```
resource "/perm/api/account/:uid/svcs",
      uid: "@uid"
    ,
      query:
        cache: true
        isArray: true
        method: "GET"
```

Service:

```
getAllResources: (uid) ->
      factory.query(uid: uid)
```

Ctrl:

```
model.getAllResources(scope.accountID).$promise.then ((response) ->
      scope.allResources = response
      resPromise.resolve()
    ), (error) ->
      log.debug error
      state.go "pageunavailable"
```

I'm trying to test this by the following:

beforeEach:

```
var def, model, service;
service = $injector.get("Service");
    model = {
    getAllResources: function() {
      def = q.defer();
      return def.promise;
    }
  };


  controller("Ctrl", {
      $scope: scope, 
      model: model
    }, service);
```

it():

```
fakeProfSvcsData = [{id:0,name:"zeon"},{id:1,name:"leo"}];
spyOn(model, "getAllResources").andCallThrough();
def.resolve(fakeProfSvcsData);
scope.$digest()

expect(scope.allResources).toEqual(fakeProfSvcsData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by modifying the following code:

Service:

```
getAllResources: (uid) ->
      factory.query(uid: uid).$promise
```

Ctrl:

```
model.getAllResources(scope.accountID).then ((response) ->
      scope.allResources = response
      resPromise.resolve()
    ), (error) ->
      log.debug error
      state.go "pageunavailable"
```

it():

```
fakeProfSvcsData = [{id:0,name:"zeon"},{id:1,name:"leo"}];
spyOn(model, "getAllResources").andReturn(def.resolve(mockProfSvcsData));
def.resolve(fakeProfSvcsData);
scope.$digest()

expect(scope.allResources).toEqual(fakeProfSvcsData);
```